# npm install mysql deletes other 50 node_modules packages?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, npm

When i run (npm install mysql) command on Fedora 27,  this command deleting other 50 node_modules packages required in program.And adding 3 mysql packages? Why is that?

```
[jatinverma95@jatinverma95 DP]$ npm install mysql
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN questionnaire@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN questionnaire@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ mysql@2.15.0
added 3 packages and removed 50 packages in 2.498s
[jatinverma95@jatinverma95 DP]$ git status
On branch sql_implemntation
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv
    deleted:    node_modules/.bin/sshpk-sign
    deleted:    node_modules/.bin/sshpk-verify
    deleted:    node_modules/.bin/uuid
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/.tonic_example.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv.min.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv.min.js.map
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/dist/nodent.min.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/dist/regenerator.min.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/$data.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.d.ts
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/cache.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/_rules.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/async.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/equal.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/error_classes.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/formats.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/resolve.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/rules.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/schema_obj.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/ucs2length.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/util.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/_limit.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/_limitItems.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/_limitLength.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/_limitProperties.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/allOf.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/anyOf.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/coerce.def
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/const.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/contains.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/custom.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/defaults.def
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/definitions.def
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/dependencies.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/enum.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/errors.def
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/format.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/items.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/missing.def
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/multipleOf.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/not.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/oneOf.jst
    deleted:    node_modules/assert-plus/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
    deleted:    node_modules/assert-plus/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/bench.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/abort.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/async.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/defer.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/iterate.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/readable_asynckit.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/readable_parallel.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/readable_serial.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/readable_serial_ordered.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/state.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/streamify.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/lib/terminator.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/parallel.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/serial.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/serialOrdered.js
    deleted:    node_modules/asynckit/stream.js
    deleted:    node_modules/aws-sign2/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/aws-sign2/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/aws-sign2/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/.tern-port
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/lru.js
    deleted:    node_modules/aws4/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/bcrypt-pbkdf/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/bcrypt-pbkdf/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/bcrypt-pbkdf/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/boom/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/boom/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/boom/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/boom/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/caseless/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/caseless/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/caseless/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/caseless/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/caseless/test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/co/History.md
    deleted:    node_modules/co/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/co/Readme.md
    deleted:    node_modules/co/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/co/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/combined-stream/License
    deleted:    node_modules/combined-stream/Readme.md
    deleted:    node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js
    deleted:    node_modules/combined-stream/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/cryptiles/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/CHANGES.md
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/LICENSE.txt
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/etc/dashdash.bash_completion.in
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/lib/dashdash.js
    deleted:    node_modules/dashdash/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/License
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/Makefile
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/Readme.md
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js
    deleted:    node_modules/delayed-stream/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/lib/LICENSE-jsbn
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/lib/ec.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/lib/sec.js
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/ecc-jsbn/test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/.eslintrc
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/.jscs.json
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/CHANGELOG.md
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/component.json
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/extend/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/.gitmodules
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/Makefile
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/Makefile.targ
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/jsl.node.conf
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/lib/extsprintf.js
    deleted:    node_modules/extsprintf/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/benchmark/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/benchmark/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/spec/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/spec/index.spec.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-deep-equal/spec/tests.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/benchmark/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/benchmark/test.json
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/example/key_cmp.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/example/nested.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/example/str.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/example/value_cmp.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/test/cmp.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/test/nested.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/test/str.js
    deleted:    node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/test/to-json.js
    deleted:    node_modules/forever-agent/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/forever-agent/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/forever-agent/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/License
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/README.md.bak
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/lib/browser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/lib/populate.js
    deleted:    node_modules/form-data/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/getpass/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/afterRequest.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/beforeRequest.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/browser.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/cache.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/content.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/cookie.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/creator.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/entry.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/har.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/header.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/log.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/page.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/pageTimings.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/postData.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/query.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/request.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/response.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/lib/timings.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-schema/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/lib/async.js
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/lib/error.js
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/lib/promise.js
    deleted:    node_modules/har-validator/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/client.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/dist/browser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/browser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/client.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/crypto.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/server.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/lib/utils.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hawk/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/lib/escape.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/hoek/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/.dir-locals.el
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/CHANGES.md
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/http_signing.md
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/lib/parser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/lib/utils.js
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
    deleted:    node_modules/http-signature/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/is-typedarray/LICENSE.md
    deleted:    node_modules/is-typedarray/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/is-typedarray/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/is-typedarray/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/is-typedarray/test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/.jshintrc
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/LICENSE.md
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/isstream.js
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/isstream/test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/example.html
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/example.js
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/jsbn/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/.eslintrc.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/fixtures/schema.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/index.spec.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-00/hyper-schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-00/json-ref
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-00/links
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-00/schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-01/hyper-schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-01/json-ref
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-01/links
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-01/schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-02/hyper-schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-02/json-ref
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-02/links
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-02/schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/examples/address
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/examples/calendar
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/examples/card
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/examples/geo
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/examples/interfaces
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/hyper-schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/json-ref
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/links
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-03/schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-04/hyper-schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-04/links
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-04/schema
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-zyp-json-schema-03.xml
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/draft-zyp-json-schema-04.xml
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/lib/links.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/lib/validate.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/json-schema/test/tests.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/CHANGELOG.md
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/Makefile
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/stringify.js
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/test/mocha.opts
    deleted:    node_modules/json-stringify-safe/test/stringify_test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/CHANGES.md
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/CONTRIBUTING.md
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/lib/jsprim.js
    deleted:    node_modules/jsprim/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/oauth-sign/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/oauth-sign/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/oauth-sign/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/.tm_properties
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/lib/performance-now.js
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/src/index.d.ts
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/test/scripts.coffee
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/test/scripts/delayed-require.coffee
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/test/scripts/difference.coffee
    deleted:    node_modules/performance-now/test/scripts/initial-value.coffee
    deleted:    node_modules/punycode/LICENSE-MIT.txt
    deleted:    node_modules/punycode/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/punycode/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/punycode/punycode.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/.History.md.un~
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/.Readme.md.un~
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/.package.json.un~
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/History.md
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/License.md
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/Readme.md
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/decode.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/encode.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/test/.index.js.un~
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/test/common-index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/test/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/querystring/test/tap-index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/CHANGELOG.md
    deleted:    node_modules/request/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/request/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/request/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/auth.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/getProxyFromURI.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/har.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/multipart.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/querystring.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
    deleted:    node_modules/request/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/request/request.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sntp/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/sntp/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/sntp/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sntp/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-sign
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-verify
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/algs.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/errors.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/auto.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pkcs1.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pkcs8.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/rfc4253.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/x509-pem.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/x509.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/ssh-buffer.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/man/man1/sshpk-conv.1
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/man/man1/sshpk-sign.1
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/man/man1/sshpk-verify.1
    deleted:    node_modules/sshpk/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/LICENSE.txt
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/example.js
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/stringstream/stringstream.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/memstore.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/pathMatch.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/permuteDomain.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/pubsuffix.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/store.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tough-cookie/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/tunnel-agent/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/tunnel-agent/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tunnel-agent/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/AUTHORS.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/CHANGELOG.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.min.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl.d.ts
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl.min.js
    deleted:    node_modules/tweetnacl/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/url/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/url/.travis.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/url/.zuul.yml
    deleted:    node_modules/url/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/url/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/url/node_modules/punycode/LICENSE-MIT.txt
    deleted:    node_modules/url/node_modules/punycode/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/url/node_modules/punycode/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/url/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js
    deleted:    node_modules/url/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/url/test.js
    deleted:    node_modules/url/url.js
    deleted:    node_modules/url/util.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/.eslintrc.json
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/AUTHORS
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/HISTORY.md
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/LICENSE.md
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/bin/uuid
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/index.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/lib/bytesToUuid.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/lib/rng-browser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/lib/rng.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/lib/sha1-browser.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/lib/sha1.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/package.json
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/v1.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/v4.js
    deleted:    node_modules/uuid/v5.js
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/.npmignore
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/CHANGES.md
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/CONTRIBUTING.md
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/LICENSE
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/README.md
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/lib/verror.js
    deleted:    node_modules/verror/package.json
    modified:   package.json

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    node_modules/bignumber.js/
    node_modules/mysql/
    node_modules/sqlstring/
    package-lock.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

[npm install mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMBzq.png)

[deleted packages-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XT7a.png)

[deleted packages-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOBld.png)

[deleted packages-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qEHk.png)

[deleted packages-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdZnB.png)

[deleted packages-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnXYH.png)

[Result of running app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26C3B.png)

[jatinverma

```
95@jatinverma95 DP]$ node app.js
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /home/jatinverma95/Jatin/DP/routes/datasets.js:10:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jatinverma95/Jatin/DP/routes/datasets.js:244:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

EDIT 1: package.json([package.json Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4lA6.png))

```
{
  "name": "questionnaire",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
    "mssql": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't commit the `node_modules` folder to Git.

Comment: @Klooven Should i make submodules for them? Would it solve this problem?

Comment: You should just commit the `package.json`. And your code of course. But it shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. @Klooven. Any idea why above thing is happening?

Comment: post your package.json

Comment: @tladuke Updated.

Comment: Try running `npm install` in the folder where you have your app.